# How long have Jewish Converts been adding "V'Sarah" to their Hebrew names? Is this Proper? Expected?

Tags: names, conversion-to-judaism

At Shul I notice that some converts have names such as "Yoseph Ben Avraham V'Sarah" and some have just "Yoseph Ben Avraham". Are both correct? Is this something new (ish)?

Comment: Does this Shul use mothers' names for any other people?

Comment: Is this shul an Orthodox one?

Comment: I have never heard of concerts being called up with v'Sarah, though I have heard ben Avraham Avinu.

Comment: I've never noticed, but I imagine you would also use ben/bat Sarah to daven for them if they're sick.   And in the yehi ratzon before taking out the Sefer Torah on the shalosh regalim.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've heard "v'Sarah Imanu" during a Mishebairach on a sick convert at my Orthodox shul.

Comment: At least in my synagogue (Reform), it would be extremely unlikely for this not to be used.

Comment: Spoke to my Rabbi about this today. His answer: Yes its a new thing and is growing in frequency, more among the more progressive movements ( as Old Bunny pointed out), but less among Orthodox. 

Yes, it is acceptable and even proper for a Mishebairach, as Mike and Heshy suggested.  

No, it is never required to be used when receiving an aliyah, even if someone has v'Sarah as part of their full converted name on their certificate.

Answer (score 5):

Reform Judaism holds egalitarianism as a core value and calls *everybody* by both father's and mother's names (if both parents are Jewish).  Converts are Ploni ben Avraham v'Sarah, but it doesn't stand out because everybody gets a matronymic.  I've heard people talk about "Avraham Avinu v'Sarah Imeinu" but I have never seen somebody be called that.

Conservative congregations, in my experience, often use both names, but there are some that only use the father's name.  (My Conservative weekday minyan recently merged into another, and in the process the default naming pattern changed.)  Again, converts are no different from anybody else in this regard.

How long have they been doing it?  I understand (anecdotally) that Reform has been using both parents' names since the 1960s or 1970s.  I don't know about Conservative.

I don't have extensive Orthodox experience, but I don't think I've ever heard somebody called by both the father's and mother's name.  This might happen in egalitarian or "partnership" minyanim; I've been to those a few times but can't recall what their naming practices were.

All of what I've said is for *aliyot* or other cases where you use a person's "usual" Hebrew name.  A *mi sheberach* for healing uses the mother's name, universally in my experience.  (I don't think I've heard both parents' names in this context in egalitarian congregations, even though you might expect that.)

Comment: Also what about the Yehi Ratzon on Yom Tov which alludes to אני עבדך בן אמתך?

Comment: @Yishai good point; you'd expect that but, now that I think about it, that's not what I've heard.  Probably somebody does it and I just haven't encountered it.

Comment: @Heshy sorry, I don't know.

Comment: That bit about Reform practice from the 60s or 70s I’d venture to say is only anecdotal. From my experience, it wasn’t the case. All in all, tldr; it is indeed “something new(ish)”.

Comment: @Oliver yes, anecdotal.  I wasn't there; I heard this from somebody who grew up in that time period, but it's unlikely to have changed everywhere at once.  But when we're talking about Jewish tradition, probably anything in the last hundred years or so counts as "newish". :-)